# Ruby 1.8.6: How to alias a constant in one class to a class method in another?

Tags: ruby, constants, alias

Is there any way to create aliases across classes?  Specifically, from a constant in one class to a class method in another?

Something like

```
Object.const_set('Foo', proc { Bar.meth })
```

except having the `proc` auto-evaluated at reference-time.  (`puts Foo` for the above displays the proc `#inspect` value; I need to execute `Foo.call` to actually *invoke* `bar.meth` -- and that's the extra step I'm trying to finesse around.)

Phrased another way, I would like to alias a constant such that when I say `puts Foo` it is exactly equivalent to `puts Bar.meth`.  If `Bar.meth` returns different values at different times, so would `Foo` evaluate to the different values accordingly -- because they're the same.

Can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want?

```
class A
  def self.bar
    "Test"
  end
end
class B
  def self.Foo
    A.bar
  end
  def self.const_missing(name)
    methods.include?(name.to_s) ? __send__(name) : super
  end
end

A.bar
B.Foo
B::Foo
# all returns "Test"
```

Comment: I think that's the key solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create alias between constants

```
class Foo
  CONST = 3
end

class Bar
  CONST = Foo::CONST
end

p Foo::CONST
# => 3
p Bar::CONST
# => 3
```

You can also reference a method into an other class. But because the value of the constant is elaborated when the assignment is evaluated, you cannot have it changing depending on an other method.

```
class Foo
  def self.const
    "value"
  end
end

class Bar
  CONST = Foo.method(:const)
end

p Foo.const
# => "value"
p Bar::CONST
# => #<Method: Foo.const>
```

You can try to cheat the interpreter by naming the method like a constant

```
class Foo
  def self.const
    "value"
  end
end

class Bar
  def self.CONST
    Foo.const
  end
end

p Foo.const
# => "value"
p Bar.CONST
# => "value"
```

but you will only be able to call `Bar.CONST`, not `Bar::CONST`.

At this point, I've got a question. Why should you do that? In my opinion, this kind of requirement seems to highlight a design issue.

Comment: Oh, if I coded specifically for this it'd be a design issue, no question. :-)  It just came up in my brain as I was trying to resolve one.  Let me play a bit with your ideas and see if that answers the question.  Thanks!

Comment: Your first code is not an "alias"; try `class Foo; C=1; end; class Bar; C = Foo::C; end; Foo::C=2; p Foo::C, Bar::C`. It will throw a warning about redefining the constant, but then this question doesn't make much sense if this is disallowed.

Comment: It looks as though you're correct, @Simone -- Ruby (at least 1.8.6) doesn't appear to let you play silly-buggers with the symbol tables.  Thanks!

Comment: @Phrogz -- I know my statements aren't alii; they were attempts to approximate the effect.  And linking a constant one class to a constant in another isn't what I'm after; I wanted to know about linking a constant in one class to a *non*-constant in another class.

Comment: @RoUS I was referring to Simone's first code block and statement, _"You can create alias between constants"_.

Answer (score 0):

The post above is really great but i was also trying things out in console and got a slightly different solution by not defining a constant in the ruby class "Object".

```
module Foo
  @output = Time.now # You can use 'Bar.meth' just showing the define at reference time
  def Foo.to_s
    @output
  end
end
```

Output:

```
$ puts Time.now
# => Tue Feb 22 22:19:23 +0100 2011
$ puts Foo
# => Tue Feb 22 22:19:19 +0100 2011
```